# What is this error? "Symbol's value as variable is void: nxml-mode-map"

Tags: init-file

I want to  create a command and a keybind to scan with `tidy` a full buffer. The keybinding has to be active only when editing XML files.

In my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file I've added the following lines:

```lisp
(defun tidy-xml ()
  "Tidies the XML content in the buffer using `tidy'"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
    (point-min) (point-max)
    "tidy -i -w 72 -q -xml"
    (current-buffer)
    t
    "*Error*"
    t))

(define-key nxml-mode-map "\C-c t" 'tidy-xml)
```

But when I open Emacs it returns the following warning:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/jim/.emacs.d/init.el’:

Symbol's value as variable is void: nxml-mode-map
```

I'm not able to see where the error is. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: The error has actually nothing to do with the shell command.

Comment: The question appears to be a duplicate. Search the site for "variable is void" to see similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `nxml-mode-map` is defined in the library `nxml-mode`.
This library is not yet loaded when you try to execute the form
 `(define-key nxml-mode-map "\C-c t" 'tidy-xml)`.
Replace that line with:

```el
(eval-after-load "nxml-mode"
  (lambda ()
    (define-key nxml-mode-map "\C-c t" 'tidy-xml)))
```

That will delay the execution of the form contained in the lambda until the library `nxml-mode` is loaded.

Comment: Or, since 24.4, use `with-eval-after-load` and then you can drop the `(lambda () ...)` wrapper.